# Which translation will be more correct?

Tags: перевод

Trying to translate the expression *«Искусство быть живым»* into English, and can't figure out which translation is correct and why? I stick to the option: *Art to be live*.But, translators issue: *The art of being alive*. Tell me, please.

Comment: Are you a native English speaker?

Comment: @SimonE, alas, no.

Comment: Me neither, but IMHO the first sentence is simply ungrammatical, regardless of the correctness of the translation. Unless you intend to live concert or something like this.

Comment: There's a number of titles (songs, movies) like The (Fine) Art of Staying Alive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I am not a native English speaker, “*The Art Of Being
Alive*” sounds much better and more natural to me.  Besides, it fits
the existing pattern set by e.g. “*The Art Of Computer
Programming*” by D.  Knuth.